# Change button color when scrolling, like a mask

Tags: jquery, css, button, parallax, mask

I would like to achieve the effect that when you scroll, a fixed button should change its appearance, just like a mask that reveals a second button. I prepared a gif to show you what I mean exactly:

[image]

Just laying both buttons on top of each other via z-index won't work, because one button always hides the other one.

Answer (score 1):

You could tackle this problem by using the CSS property `margin-top` in combination with jQuery's [`scrollTop()`](http://api.jquery.com/scrolltop/) listener. Here's something I quickly put together:

### jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(window).scroll(function (event) {
        var scroll = $('body').scrollTop();
        var margin = $("#redArea").height()-$("#container").height() - $("#container").css("margin-top").replace("px", "");
        // Display the current scrollTop()
        $("#divOne").html(scroll);
        
        if (scroll > margin && scroll-margin < $("#container").height()) {
            $('#divOne').css("margin-top","-"+(scroll-margin)+"px");  
        } else if (scroll > margin) {
            $('#divOne').css("margin-top","-"+$("#container").height()+"px"); 
        } else {
            $('#divOne').css("margin-top","0px"); 
        }
    });
});
```

Especially important is that you construct a general 'button container' which holds both versions of the button. You then change the margin property of the upper image when the `.scrollTop()` reaches a certain threshold margin (the ending of the red area). When this happens, you make the `margin-top` property of the upper image equal to the next scrolling offset. Also note how I have an extra `else if` statement which makes sure that the image changes if the user scrolls *too* quickly. Apart from this jQuery, also make sure you have your CSS set properly.

Here's the corresponding jsFiddle:

[image]

## [> jsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/oeLgyqzo/)

There are 2 important things to note before using my code:

- The (ugly) images I used have been quickly taken as a screenshot from your gif
- This might not work in all versions of IE

So take a good look at the HTML, Javascript ***and*** CSS. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you Jean-Paul for your in-depth reply. Will try this out later today.

Comment: @user1462382 Sure :) Good luck. You can achieve this effect in multiple ways but the key point to take away from my solution is that you need a container to hold the two versions of the button. Then manipulate the container to get the effect.

Comment: @user1462382: Did you try it out? If you did, consider accepting my answer.